# How to handle backbuffer in Direct3D11?

Tags: c++, direct3d

Recently,i want to learn a book named Tricks of 3D Games Programming Gurus.It used DDraw to implement a soft render engine.But DDraw is to old.I want to use Direct3D11 to do the same things.So i got the texture of the main backbuffer,and update it.But it didn't work,what should i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have direct access to the true frontbuffer/backbuffer even with DirectDraw on modern platforms.

If you want to do all your rendering into a block of CPU memory without using the GPU, then your best bet for fast presentation is to use a Direct3D 11 texture with `D3D11_USAGE_DYNAMIC`, and then do a simple full-screen quad render of that texture onto the presentation backbuffer. For that step, you can look at [DirectX Tool Kit](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK) and the `SpriteBatch` class.

That said, performance wise this is likely to be pretty poor because you are doing everything on the CPU and the GPU is basically doing nothing 99% of the time.

Comment: Thanks for your idea.I have solved the problem with your solution.